# Scheme pair construction

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, cons, cdr

I am trying to understand pair construction and representation.
Let's take a look at the following results:

```
(length (cons '(a b) '(d e f)))
=> 4
```

Now let's switch the order:

```
(length (cons '(d e f) '(a b)))
 => 3
```

but

```
(length (car (cons '(d e f) '(a b))))
=> 3
```

Could you please explain the results above?
What is the difference between car and cdr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `cons` simply sticks together two things, for historical reasons the first one is referred to as `car` and the second one as `cdr`.

If the second one happens to be a proper list, then the result is also a list. Hence a list is defined as the result of `cons`ing one element with the result of `cons`ing one element ... and so on, until we reach the empty list `'()`. For example:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
=> '(1 2 3)
```

When dealing with lists, think of `car` as the first element of the list and `cdr` as the rest of the elements, and `cons` adds one more element at the head of the list - that element can be anything, *including another list*. It just gets added at the head, the lists are not "merged" (we use `append` for that). Take a look:

```
(car '(1 2 3))
 => 1

(cdr '(1 2 3))
=> '(2 3)
```

Now, regarding your examples - the first one adds `'(a b)` as the first element of a list, where the rest is `'(d e f)`, so we now have a 4 element list, like this:

```
(cons '(a b) '(d e f))
=> '((a b) d e f)
```

Similarly for the second example: we add the first element `'(d e f)` to the rest of the elements `'(a b)`, and we get a 3 element list:

```
(cons '(d e f) '(a b))
=> '((d e f) a b)
```

Finally, if we call `car` on the above list, we get its first element - which happens to be `'(d e f)`, and clearly it has 3 elements:

```
(car (cons '(d e f) '(a b)))
=> '(d e f)
```